# How to Update an Existing Data Structure When We need to Maintain Legacy Support?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, serialization

So long story short, we have an aging application that's acquired some cruft over the years we've been developing it. There's a few bolted-on things that have been starting to cause problems though, and it got me thinking about how we could structure the data a bit better. The problem with this, though, is that we *NEED* to maintain support for older serialised data files that our clients might have, which makes it very difficult to migrate to a new build if we make any sweeping changes to our classes.

My question is, is there a good, tested process/architecture pattern that could potentially help us in the future should we decide to invest some effort in refactoring the code?

**EDIT** It's all binary serialization

Comment: What serialization format is the legacy code using? (XML or Binary)

Comment: Binary. I am looking for something a little more generic, though, that way I can apply it elsewhere later on :)

Comment: A [versioned serialisation model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683501/versioning-serialized-files) is what you need, so I guess you need to add a "version" property to the serialised data. For anything without a version, treat that as "version 0"...

Comment: Ah, ok, and then we could implement a strategy for each version of the data. That makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just thinking out loud, but something akin to the way COM used to "version" things might work..something akin to:

```
[Serializable]
public class Data
{
    public string Field1 {get; set;}
}

[Serializable]
public class Data2
{
    public Data2() { _version1 = new Data();}

    [NonSerialized]
    private Data _version1; 
    public string Field1 
    { 
        get { return _version1.Field1;} 
        set { _version1.Field1 = value;}
    }
    public int Field2 {get; set;}
}

[Serializable]
public class Data3
{
    public Data3() { _version2 = new Data2();}

    [NonSerialized]
    private Data2 _version2;
    public string Field1 
    { 
        get { return _version2.Field1;} 
        set { _version2.Field1 = value;}
    }
    public int Field2 
    { 
        get { return _version2.Field2;} 
        set { _version2.Field2 = value;}
    }
    public double Field3 {get; set;}    
}
```

Actually, now that I'm looking at this laid out in front of me, I can't say it's anything close to an ideal solution. It'd quickly lead to a proliferation of "version number hell", which is much like what COM is these days (check out the various DirectX interface names sometime)

That said, it *is* a potential answer, so I'll leave it.

Comment: Hmm, this is interesting. I was thinking along these lines, but I was wondering if I should maybe pull out an interface so I can restructure the data while still being able to talk to the application. It's nice to know someone else is on the same wavelength. I think if you were using a DI framework, version numbers would be less of an issue